# What is the name of this recliner couch screw holder?

Tags: tools, furniture, hand-tools

My Recliner Couch is missing a few of these Pieces that hold the screw in place between the metals. I am trying to get some new ones but I don' know what they are called and where I can buy them. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a brand name for the recliner?

Comment: If those are threaded, it's a _standoff_, if not they are just _spacers_.

Comment: Thanks I am not to sure about the brand of the recliner I will have to double check to see if I can find the name. I don't think they are threaded.Yeah I think spacers are the  name I was looking for. At least I have a name now lol

Comment: @JACK The inf I foound is  made by Jiaxing Xianglong Metals Products, co

Comment: If you have the right friend,  give them one of these and in a couple days they will have copied it into CAD and 3D-printed a bunch for you.

Comment: No i don't know anyone. But now that I know the name maybe any spacer may do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't really matter what they're called. They're almost certainly proprietary and shown in an exploded parts diagram somewhere with a number next to them. You won't find them in hardware stores (real or online).

You'll need to get in touch with the manufacturer one way or another, or you'll need to fabricate something that performs the same function without the efficiency of design afforded by that exact part. It could be that a block of nylon with dimples drilled in each face does the job, for example, or maybe a sleeve nut and some bolts.

Comment: Well I needed to know it was called a spacer. Because I think any spacer will do. ali its really doing is preventing the  metal from going all the way down

Comment: What about cutting to the right length a piece of 1" wooden dowel, drilling an axial hole the right diameter to thread onto the bolt? What is the function of the "waist" on the part?

Comment: I wouldn't trust wood in this role. It's likely to split on the grain.